# Configurating Django, Heroku, and a static file server

Tags: django, heroku, file-upload, nginx

We used to use the following combination: Django framework with Heroku as the application server and Amazon S3 as the static file server.

But recently we need to build a system which handles a large amount of video data, with data transfer more than 10 TB per month. That means Amazon S3 is no longer an option because it's too expensive.

We opt to set up our own static file server, so it's gonna be Django, Heroku, and an on-premiss file server. We need some suggestions:

1. Is our decision good enough? Any other options?
2. Is Nginx a good choice for the file server in this application?
3. Are there good documentations about uploading large files from a Django+Heroku application to a Nginx server?

Thanks.

Comment: AWS S3 is good for storage but HTTPS endpoint itself is not secure, something should be in front: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=s3%2deu%2dwest%2d1.amazonaws.com&s=54.231.129.57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, your decision is best possible one

2) Nginx is the very best solution. Cloudflare serves traffic with Nginx more than major web apps altogether. Netflix serves 33% all US media traffic with Nginx

3) S3 as an origin is not expensive but traffic costs a lot. That should help https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files

Large files upload should bypass any kind of backend but saved on disk asynchronous followed by upload to any destination with s separate process. For big files upload you have be careful of authentication, normally authentication happens only after file is uploaded which can be dangerous. To solve that try https://coderwall.com/p/swgfvw/nginx-direct-file-upload-without-passing-them-through-backend